# The Dependency Inversion Principle with .NET Framework classes

Tags: c#, software-design, solid-principles

I'm trying to understand SOLID principles, in particular **The Dependency Inversion Principle**.

In this is [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41925051/68571) it is explained very well.

I think I have understood that I can't create any instance of a class inside my class. Is it right?

But if I have to save to disk some content, can I create an instance of [System.IO.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) or do I have to inject it?

I don't understand where is the limit, if I can't instance my own classes or if I can't either instance .NET Framework classes (or whatever other framework).

**UPDATE**:
I think `File` is a bad example because is declared as static.

By the way, **does this principle apply to static classes**?

Comment: You would probably want use the instance of `System.IO.File` inside a method right? You don't inject methods, but classes so I don't see a problem here. What I mean is, wrap it inside a service and inject that.

Comment: Actually you may want to inject your own file management interface (of which one concrete implementation does create a `File` object but nothing more), otherwise your code will become impossible to test.

Comment: You wouldn't have to inject that but you could inject your own FileService or something similar to handle the saving to disk

Comment: I think File is a bad example because it is declared as static: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,1c7421e464f67b7e

Comment: As @DavidG said, inject your own IFileSaver and use that to save the file. It helps with testing and mocking of your service

Comment: A common example of this is the `DateTime.Now` method, you should see plenty of code snippets that show you how you would abstract that into an interface. (e.g. an `IDateTimeNowProvider`)

Comment: @DavidG Ok, I think I have to reformulate my question: How can I use `System.IO.File` without violating the dependency inversion principle? Or maybe I haven't understood the injection of my own file manager interface.

Comment: @DavidG awesome comment, I was exactly giving this example in my answer. It may look overthinking, but I actually think this is a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

The S of **SOLID** stands for SRP (Single Responsibility Principle). You won't violate it by using `System.IO.File` inside a class directly, once you keep that class with one single responsibility.

It's a good idea trying to abstract the purpose behind using `System.IO.File`. Let's suppose you need it to generate a log. Then you would probably do something like:

```
public interface IMyLogger
{
    void GenerateLog(IEnumerable<string> content);
}

public class FileLogger: IMyLogger
{
    public void GenerateLog(IEnumerable<string> content)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:/Log", content);
    }
}
```

Maybe it's not just a log, it's something more important, like generating a file so other system/app (even external) read it and do some job.

If you are trying to use a DDD approach, the interface could belong to your domain, and the implementation could belong in the application. Then you register your interface as a service and inject it.

The class which needs an `IMyLogger` actually doesn't need to know how is the log being generated, it just needs the job to be done.

You can apply the same idea when you need to send an email inside some business logic in your domain. Instead of making a connection to an Exchange inside your domain directly, create an interface `INotifier` and a `MailNotifier` implementing it to be injected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But you are using `System.IO.File` in your `FileLogger` class without injecting it. Where does injection stop? Does your `FileLogger` class violating that principle? Maybe I'm confuse or I haven't understood anything.

Comment: You're welcome. No, once the only purpose of my `FileLogger` is to use `System.IO.File` to generate logs. SOLID tells us about the Single Responsibility Principle, which in short means we shouldn't use a class/service to do all the sort of things, it should have one responsibility. If you have a class that do some calculus and at the same time uses `System.IO.File` after that, that class already has more than one responsibility, thus violating SRP (the S of SOLID). That's why `FileLogger` is not violating it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have understood your answer but I'm asking about the **D** principle, not the **S**. It is strange for me that I can create an instance of a class in another class without violating the dependency inversion principle. Thanks.

Comment: @VansFannel I like to think each of SOLID statements work together. Like Kapol explained, you will eventually need to use `System.IO.File` somewhere. My idea here is quite simple, I'm just creating a wrapper for it, and extracting an interface from it to be injected. Therefore, you apply D with respect to S. You would violate D if you had a class which **did not have** the responsibility to write files to disk, but used `System.IO.File` inside it, instead of asking for a service (like `IMyLogger`) to be injected. Actually you would be violating D and S, that's why I think they work together.

Comment: You would inject the logger. `IMyLogger` is a contract for a logging service. `FileLogger` is an implementation of this service. The word "service" is used in a very general sense and just designates a piece of code that does something for you and has nothing to do with a web service or the like. Generally, you are injecting services and components.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere down the chain of dependencies you will need to use the concrete class directly. Even if you use a DI framework like Ninject, the framework itself will create an instance of the concrete type, so it will not be injected into the framework (which wouldn't make sense, of course).

You can only abstract something away to a certain level. It will vary from project to project - you have to ask yourself if you need another level of abstraction (be it for modularity, unit testing etc.). I think this is very important - you want to be pragmatic, not create layers upon layers of abstractions just for the sake of it.

> By the way, does this principle apply to static classes?

Yes, it does. But with static classes you have to introduce a wrapper, which will delegate calls to the static class, because a static class cannot implement interfaces.

Comment: Static behavior can be simulated by a singleton object that can be injected. In most DI frameworks allow you to specify the lifetime of an object as `singleton`. I.e. they would always return the same instance of a service you ask for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in applying a principle just for the sake of it. Think in a pragmatic way.

If you want to unit-test a method that uses hard coded file accesses, your unit tests will access these files. This is usually not desired as you must set up or clean up these files. To avoid this, you would inject a service which wraps these file accesses. This allows you to replace the real service with a fake one during the unit tests. This fake service can provide hard coded test data for read accesses and dump written data to memory for later analysis or simply do nothing. Btw.: [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/) can create fake services at runtime easily.

The injection of services allows you to achieve Unit Test Isolation. E.g. you can test some logic without depending on correct file handling or database accesses or the correct functioning of other services. Injecting a service is just one way to do it. You could also just specify a method parameter as `IEnumerable<string>` with the content of the file instead. Events can also be used for decoupling. Instead of writing to a log, you could raise a log event.

---

Most DI frameworks allow you to specify the lifetime of objects. One of these options is `Singleton`, which means that the DI container will always return the same instance of a requested service. This allows you to wrap static classes in a service that behaves statically.